# Excel table VBA - Select new last row cell 2 as active

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code. It does not select the newly created row...

I have a macro button called ADD NEW which links to code that successfully adds a new last row in a table and generates a new number in the first cell of the table. but it does not set as active and 'go to' the second cell to begin user ....
what am I missing?

```
Sub Add_New()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim the_table As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim last_row As Long

Set the_sheet = Sheets("Inventory")
Set the_table = the_sheet.ListObjects("tbl_Data")
Set table_object_row = the_table.ListRows.Add
Set last_row = the_sheet.Range("C1`" & .Rows.Count).End(x1up).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: You need something like `table_object_row.Range.Cells(1).Activate` or `Application.GoTo(table_object_row.Range.Cells(1))`. These are untested, but the general idea is that you've set the references needed, but you haven't done anything with them. BTW I don't think you need last row for this, since it's referring to the newly added row. If you do need it then you need to remove the `Set` at the beginning, as that's for `Ranges`. And you need qualify the `.Rows` part, i.e. specify where the rows are.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
table_object_row.range.cells(1,1).select
```

(Assuming these rows are the same as worksheet rows)

BTW, correct this line

```
Set last_row = the_sheet.Range("C1`" & .Rows.Count).End(x1up).Row
```

to

```
last_row= Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A1" & Worksheets("Inventory").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: `last_row` is a long, so can't be selected.

Comment: Your previous edit worked, although I think you are on the right track about just selecting the table row (or maybe a cell in it).  However, `table_object_row.select` will give you a runtime error.

Comment: OK I think I found it, table_object_row.range.cells(1,1).select , seems to work for me, updating answer.

Comment: This looks good to me. You could just use `Cells(1)` and maybe `Activate` instead of `Select` but those are quibbles :-)

Comment: @Thomas Inzina the line you corrected was meant to point to the incorrect original line

Comment: This is my corrected code.  It works IF I don't have data filtered in the table. If filtered, it seems to add the auto number to an existing row of data....Is there a code fix that will always Add a NEW ROW to the END of the table and not to the END of the filtered data???

Comment: `Sub Add_New()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim the_table As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim last_row As Long

Set the_sheet = Sheets("Inventory")
Set the_table = the_sheet.ListObjects("tbl_Data")
Set table_object_row = the_table.ListRows.Add
 table_object_row.Range.Cells(1, 1).Select
Set last_row = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C1" & Worksheets("Inventory").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End Sub`

Comment: @DougGlancy sorry if I am not following post formatting correctly;)  see above comment of the filtered issue and code revision. Unsure if I should have included your tags above.